# How to add indexes to the following examples？

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, datagrip

```
SELECT UNIT_PRICE
FROM ORDER_DETAIL
WHERE QUANTITY IN (100, 200, 300) OR
DISCOUNT = 0.01;
```

My query:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT UNIT_PRICE FROM ORDER_DETAIL WHERE QUANTITY IN (100, 200, 300) OR DISCOUNT = 0.01;`
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
CREATE INDEX OD_IDX_QD ON ORDER_DETAIL(QUANTITY, DISCOUNT);
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT UNIT_PRICE FROM ORDER_DETAIL WHERE QUANTITY IN (100, 200, 300) OR DISCOUNT = 0.01;
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
DROP INDEX OD_IDX_QD;
```

[image: Before adding index]

[image: After adding index]

How to add index correctly in this case？

Comment: Hi, as per the snippet you have successfully created the index. If your question is why an index is not used in this particular instance it could be due to many factors. (eg: if majority of the records are being returned in the select query, then optimizer would evaluate correctly that using an index could be more expensive)

Comment: Another point in general is that index <> fast query (It depends on many factors, statistics on objects, cached plan, selectivity of query, skewed data etc )

Comment: Yeah my question is why this index is not used in this particular instance. My table is empty so whats the reason for that.

Comment: if the table is empty it would be easier to navigate directly to table rather than use an index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query contains OR that's why you can't get index range scan.
You can create one more index for DISCOUNT and add hint OR_EXPAND, in this case you will get UNION ALL with 2 index range scans (or-expansion transformation)

(Oracle 12.2+: https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/optimizer-transformations:-or-expansion )

```
CREATE INDEX OD_IDX_D ON ORDER_DETAIL(DISCOUNT);

EXPLAIN PLAN FOR 
SELECT/*+ or_expand */ UNIT_PRICE FROM ORDER_DETAIL WHERE QUANTITY IN (100, 200, 300) OR DISCOUNT = 0.01;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
-- output
Plan hash value: 4033578183
 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                 |     4 |    52 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  VIEW                                  | VW_ORE_1606201E |     4 |    52 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   UNION-ALL                            |                 |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | ORDER_DETAIL    |     1 |    26 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | OD_IDX_D        |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    INLIST ITERATOR                     |                 |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| ORDER_DETAIL    |     3 |    90 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | OD_IDX_QD       |     3 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   4 - access("DISCOUNT"=0.01)
   7 - access("QUANTITY"=100 OR "QUANTITY"=200 OR "QUANTITY"=300)
       filter(LNNVL("DISCOUNT"=0.01))
```

Or if you oracle version is pretty old, you can use hint use_concat:

```
CREATE INDEX OD_IDX_D ON ORDER_DETAIL(DISCOUNT);

EXPLAIN PLAN FOR 
SELECT/*+ use_concat */ UNIT_PRICE 
FROM ORDER_DETAIL OD
WHERE QUANTITY IN (100, 200, 300) OR DISCOUNT = 0.01;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
Plan hash value: 819751077
 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |              |     4 |   120 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  CONCATENATION                        |              |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | ORDER_DETAIL |     1 |    30 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | OD_IDX_D     |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |   INLIST ITERATOR                     |              |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| ORDER_DETAIL |     3 |    90 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | OD_IDX_QD    |     3 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   3 - access("DISCOUNT"=0.01)
   6 - access("QUANTITY"=100 OR "QUANTITY"=200 OR "QUANTITY"=300)
       filter(LNNVL("DISCOUNT"=0.01))
```

**Update**: comments are not convenient to answer for you additional question, so I'm answering here:

Because your query contains OR:

```
WHERE QUANTITY IN (100, 200, 300) OR DISCOUNT = 0.01;
```

If you analyze your query, you can find out that is the same as

```
select UNIT_PRICE 
from (
    SELECT rowid, UNIT_PRICE FROM ORDER_DETAIL WHERE QUANTITY IN (100, 200, 300) 
    union
    SELECT rowid, UNIT_PRICE FROM ORDER_DETAIL WHERE DISCOUNT = 0.01
)
```

where first part of union all can use your index, because it starts from that column
but not second part, since you didn't provide range for the first column of the index.In this case oracle can use INDEX SKIP SCAN, but it's not effective in this case.
So you need another index for that.

Comment: My previous index is based on `QUANTITY` and `DISCOUNT`, and I don't understand creating a index for `DISCOUNT`.

Comment: Because your query contains OR:
SELECT UNIT_PRICE 
FROM ORDER_DETAIL 
WHERE 
QUANTITY IN (100, 200, 300) 
OR DISCOUNT = 0.01;`

Comment: Thank you I need some time to understand it fully. What about adding index to 'QUANTITY' and 'DISCOUNT'  seperately.

Comment: I've just added expanded answer to my post, since comments don't allow long answers. 
>What about adding index to 'QUANTITY' and 'DISCOUNT' seperately
Depends... Yes - if you have not queries predicates with AND: like DISCOUNT in ... AND QUANTITY =...

Comment: "My previous index is based on QUANTITY and DISCOUNT".. When you create an index on multiple columns, The selectivity of the index is in the order of the columns in the index, not on each column separately.  And regardless of _any_ indexing, the optimizer may still very well decide that the index is not selective enough to justify the extra index reads vs. simply scanning the table.

Comment: @EdStevens there a lot of different factors. For example, in case of low selectivity, but with all needed columns in the index (or indexes), Oracle can choose full scan from those indexes (ie INDEX FULL SCAN or INDEX FAST FULL SCAN) (and with "BITMAP AND" + "Bitmap Conversion FROM Rowid" in case of multiple indexes)